# Any code fixes for "ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons"

Tags: server

I have two clients using Craft and their hosts will not allow ini_set as they have it as a disabled function in the global php.ini.  I also can't enable in througth a custom php.ini.  Is there any way to modify Craft to get past the ini_set issues?  I have the site all setup, the pages work locally, when I upload to the server we just see a blank page.

Any advice is appreciated as they both do not want to change hosts.

Thanks.

Comment: Brad said this should be addressed in version 3 but anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code fix is to put an @ sign before every call to `ini_set` that Craft makes and all of Craft's dependencies in `craft/app/vendor` suppressing the error message `@ini_set()`.

But I definitely wouldn't recommend that as you'll have to maintain some 40+ hacks across nearly as many files that could get blown away during any auto-update.

Comment: What is the big risk with ini_set anyway. Allowing a php.ini file is just as bad I would think if not worse. Trying to figure out while hosts are disabling it. With SuPHP I would think it would not matter.

Comment: I've yet to read a good argument for disabling it other than the generic "security think of the children!" one.

Comment: I will convince them to host with us if possible as we don't disable it. Never had any issues on our servers. Thanks Brad.